# ExtJs Grid: misalignment of grid lines for header and body cells

Tags: extjs

**Issue Description:**

I have a grid with 60+ columns.

When I set the column width at runtime, the grid lines for header and body cells are not aligned.

Here's the code I use to set column widths:

```
var clns = grid.getVisibleColumns();
Ext.each(clns,
             function (column) {
                 column.setWidth(150);
             });
```

Picture showing grid line alignment issue:
[image: Picture showing grid line alignment issue]

**ExtJS version tried:**
7.4.0;
7.0

**Steps to reproduce the issue:**

Here’s the fiddle to reproduce this issue:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3du3

1. Click on any row (except the first) to set column
   widths
2. Scroll to the right to see the columns on the far right
   side of the grid
3. You will see the grid lines for header and body
   cells are not aligned

This issue is dependent on Text Scale Level:

| Resolution | Text Scale | Alignment Issue occurs? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3840x2160 | 250% | No |
| 3840x2160 | 225% | Yes |
| 2560x2048 | 150% | No |
| 2560x2048 | 225% | Yes |
| 1960x1200 | 150% | No |
| 1960x1200 | 175% | Yes |

Does anyone know why this issue occurs, and how to resolve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This issue appeared to be browser-specific. This issue did not occur in Firefox but did occur in Chrome & Edge.

Upgrading Google Chrome to the latest version (Version 91.0.4472.77 (64-bit)) resolved the issue.

I tested at various text scale - 125%, 150%, 175%, 200%, 225%, 250%, 300%, 350% - and the grid lines stayed aligned in all those cases.